# Travel charger usage on the plane (KLM)

Tags: aircraft, power, klm

Has any had any experience of charging mobile devices on the plane? I am catching a flight to NY from London (KLM/Delta Airlines) and need to be entertained using my phone. I wonder how I can manage to keep the charge level good (even though I will be switching the aeroplane mode).

Is there any solution or has anyone got any answers?

Comment: Have you checked seatguru.com to see if your flight will offer in-seat power?

Comment: @choster          Certainly can't say that I've...will look into it now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the commonts say, check seatguru to see if you're likely to have at-seat power. I don't recall every being on a Delta or KLM flight that had at seat power in economy, they most likely will in business. If it's got a newer version of the in-seat entertainment it *might* have a USB socket and that *might* be powered, although it depends (again, check seatguru) and it also depends how power hungry your mobile device is.

I carry a portable battery pack that will recharge my phone fully a few times or recharge my tablet about half to three-quarters. Having that fully charged and my tablet fully charged gets about eight to ten hours of use which is normally enough for me.

Also, get an app that monitors battery usage (you'll already be in flight mode which helps with the battery drain), close out apps you're not using, turn down the brightness. There are a lot of things you can do to minimize the battery usage of a device.